# combine 2 Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

i have a problem here.

```
    //this post data containt two array.    
    $titleArray = $_POST['data1']; // Array Project Manager, System Analist, ...
    $nameArray = $_POST['data2']; // Array Gabriel, Anna, Rey, ...
```

and i whant the result like this:

```
    array (
           ["Project Manager"] => Gabriel
           ["System Analist"] => Anna
           ["Programmer"] => Jhon
           ["Designer"] => Rey
)
```

and/or i whant to print like this:

```
echo $key . ":" . $value;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**array_combine**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) — *Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values*

```
$result = array_combine($titleArray , $nameArray);

foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
   echo $key . ":" . $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to merge two array

```
$result = array_merge($titleArray, $nameArray);
print_r($result);
```

Or to combine first array for key and second for values

```
$result = array_combine($titleArray , $nameArray);
```

or for print use **foreach**

```
foreach($result as $key=>$value) {
  echo $key. ":" .$value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$titleArray = array('Project Manager','System Analist','Programmer','Designer');
$nameArray  = array('Gabriel','Anna','Jhon','Rey');
$output = array_combine($titleArray,$nameArray);


foreach($output as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.": ".$value.'<br>';
}
```

ouput

```
Project Manager: Gabriel
System Analist: Anna
Programmer: Jhon
Designer: Rey
```

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP documentation you can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
<?php
$array1 = $_POST['data1'];
$array2 = $_POST['data2'];
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```